# Deleting Tor bookmarks

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security

Long story short : I don't like the idea of adding bookmarks with Tor, but I accidentally created one by hitting the shortcut.

For my knowledge and to prevent further mistakes like this one, where are located bookmarks on Tor, and how can I delete them permanently ?

I'm on Windows, and I'm using the regular Tor Browser Bundle.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer [from official forum](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/833585) - Tor Browser Bundle is a Firefox, tweaked a bit. So - the same file hierarchy preserved. Your case is `places.sqlite`