# Remove bookmarks from tor browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security, browsers, torproject.org

I use tor browser and have some bookmarks. Now I want to remove those bookmarks completely. I already tried approach mentioned on [this link](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/10197/deleting-tor-bookmarks). I deleted places.sqlite file but all my bookmarks are still there.

**How can I successfully delete all bookmarks completely?**

Comment: are you sure that the Tor browser is using that folder? maybe you have multiple tor installations?

Comment: @marcin-c I have only one installation. And yes it is using that folder because when I follow instructions given in the link(which is in my question) then it opens that folder.

Comment: Please don't re-create a question that has been asked before, if you have an issue with the answer then comment on it or flag it or better yet, improve it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the Tor Browser from
   https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en
2. Copy `<old-browser>/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/state` to `<new-browser>/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/state` to preserve your entry guards.
3. Delete your old Tor Browser.
4. Use the Tor Browser you have just downloaded.